# ArcGIS 10 Raster Mosaicing versus Lizardtech Express Server

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster

Trying to determine if I still need to use [Lizardtech Express Server](http://www.lizardtech.com/products/exp/) to mosaic rasters together or just use the [Mosaic Raster Dataset function](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_mosaic_dataset/009t0000003p000000/) of ArcGIS 10? I know for earlier releases of Express Server and ArcGIS you could find info on tying the 2 together but I can't seem to find anything about it now. I've learned that when the silence is deafening on a topic it generally means that "[they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_man)" want it to just die and go away. Help me StackExchange GIS, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 1):

I've used mrsid files in mosaic datasets in arc10.0.  Personally, I've found alot of the times the internal pyramids of mrsid files screw with the quality of my mosaics.  I'm assuming that storage space is an issue, which is why you are using a mrsid over a tif?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Express Server but it's worth noting that ArcGIS currently does not support MrSID Generation 4 (MG4), although this is [targeted for 10.1](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/23714-MrSid-Generation-4?p=79632&viewfull=1#post79632).

LizardTech makes an [MG4 plugin](http://www.lizardtech.com/downloads/plugins.php) for ArcGIS Desktop, but I am not sure if this is compatible with mosaic datasets, and it obviously wouldn't work on ArcGIS Server.

Answer (score 0):

I think a relevant question might be whether or not you actually need to mosaic the images together.  What benefit do you see in having them all as one image, vs having each load individually?  I ask this because I have used the [ArcGIS Raster Catalog](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Adding_a_raster_catalog_to_a_map) extensively for my projects.  It lets you reference individual rasters, creates a layer containing the boundaries for each one, and loads them all as a single entity.  What is extremely useful is that it controls the loading of the rasters, so if you have a them in a grid, you can choose to load only the ones within your data frame.
This could be less data intensive than loading in a mosaiced dataset, though with a MrSID raster, that is less of an issue.